# Change div background image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, class

Hey guys, I'm trying to change the background image of multiple divs with the class .innerpreview when a drop down selection is made. Any idea why the following isn't working?

```
$('#txtMontage').change(function(event) {
    if (this.value == "example") {
        $('.innerpreview').css('background-image', 'img/img-bkg.jpg)');
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are missing the "url()" bit of setting the background image.  You should have something like this:

```
$('#txtMontage').change(function(event) {
    if (this.value == "example") {
        $('.innerpreview').css('background-image', 'url(img/img-bkg.jpg)');
    }
});
```

See this question: [Switching DIV Background Image With jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253689/switching-div-background-image-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks Ender, missed that.  But I stand behind my statement to use a CSS class for this.

Answer (score 4):

Missing url( ... thanks Ender:

```
$('#txtMontage').change(function(event) {
    if (this.value == "example") {
        $('.innerpreview').css('background-image', 'url(img/img-bkg.jpg)');
    }
});
```

I would also not use this, but create a new class in CSS with the background image specified, and change or add this new class.