# How do I change the background image using jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery, image, animation, background

I want to change the background image using slow animation, but its not working

```
 $('body').stop().animate({background:'url(1.jpg)'},'slow');
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax!!

Comment: What is not working? The speed or any of it?

Comment: now the image is not coming up!! when i click function event!!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can get a similar effect by fading the image opacity to 0, then change the background image, and finally fading the image back in again.

This will require a div, behind everything else on your page which is as wide as the body.

```
<body>
    <div id="bg"></div>
    ...
</body>
```

You can make it as wide as the page using CSS:

```
#bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

And then animate it's properties.

```
$('#bg')
    .animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
        $(this)
            .css({'background-image': 'url(1.jpg)'})
            .animate({opacity: 1});
    });
```

You could get more of a crossover effect, by having a second background div on top of this one, which you can then fade in.

Comment: This would work, except that it would animate the opacity of all the content of `body` as well. I'm not sure that's what OP is after.

Comment: @patrick of course, well there is no way I know of (without a plugin) to animate the background opacity, so maybe some extra HTML is required to get this effect?

Comment: @Marcus: Yes, you're right, it would require some extra HTML, like an element positioned at a z-index lower than the rest of the content and stretched out to the full width/height of the body. EDIT: I see you already updated. Nice solution. +1

Comment: `.css({'background-image': 'url(img/'result.bgimage')'})` how can i put this callback data in the url

Comment: @getaway I am not sure what you mean exactly. You can do `'background-image': 'url(img/result.bgimage)'`

Comment: +1 for providing a valid workaround instead of saying that animate() doesn't traditionally work with images (like the answers to similar questions). Has potential to help many programmers.

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery documentation:

> properties that are non-numeric cannot
>   be animated using basic jQuery
>   functionality. (For example, width,
>   height, or left can be animated but
>   background-color cannot be.)

Source: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @getaway With jQuery UI? Or some plug-in?

Comment: background-COLOR is numeric and can be animated.
background-IMAGE is non-numeric and cannot be animated

Answer (score 1):

You can't animate the adding/replacing of a background image. The URL is either there or not. There's no in between state.

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve this may be to onclick add a new class with the background image in. Then animate this?
Or fade out the image to reveal a new one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253689/switching-div-background-image-with-jquery I'm on the iPhone so it's difficult. But some of the answers here may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a faux div to cover the background as a fixed element and then animate that element i.e:

```
<div id="bgDiv" style='display:none;background:URL("Water lilies.jpg");position:fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -1'></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#bgDiv').toggle(1000); //You can plugin animate function here.

    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
$(this).animate({
    opacity: 0
}, 100, function() {
    // Callback
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + new_img + ")").promise().done(function(){
        // Callback of the callback :)
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 600)
    });    
});
```