# Body Background Changer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, document-body

Alright here it is.

Simply, I want to be able to have the background of the body via CSS fade out and change every so often and then loop.

Any ideas how I can achieve this with CSS and jQuery?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jquery animate method and when it completes call the method again with a new color:

```
var color = ["red","green","blue"];
var i = 0;

function changeColor()
{
 // Change to the next color over 2 seconds.  When it is done, call this method again.
 $("body").animate({"background-color":color[i]}, 2000, changeColor); 
 i++;  // Increment the counter so the next color in the array is shown
 i = i % 3;   // Make sure i is never greater than 2 by using the modulous.
}

changeColor();
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/vDCSw/5/

​

Comment: That's awesome! But how would I do it with a Background Image? Thank you very much!

Comment: You have to use a div and then animate the image on that by doing some cross fading.  See this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4630947/573218