# jQuery to change (with fade animation) background image of div on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I am trying to change the background image of a div on hover with jQuery.
This is what I came up so far, however, it's not working:

**html**

```
<div class="logo"></div>
```

**css**

```
.logo {
 width: 300px;
 height: 100px;
 background: url('http://placehold.it/300x100/ffffff/000000.png&text=first') no-repeat center top;
}
```

**js**

```
$('.logo').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundImage: 'http://placehold.it/300x100/ffffff/000000.png&text=second'},'fast');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundImage: 'http://placehold.it/300x100/ffffff/000000.png&text=first'},'fast');
});
```

**jsfiddle** here: http://jsfiddle.net/26j6P/1/

What am I doing wrong?
If I animate the background color, it works just fine...

Comment: jQuery's animate doesn't work with images.  You'll need to use css and transitions to get this to work.

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630947/how-do-i-change-the-background-image-using-jquery-animation

Comment: it would be better to just do the hover in css .logo:hover {/*new img here*/} if you really want to user jQuery try with fadeIn(), fadeOut() and not animate

Comment: Thanks for the head-up. I never thought that jQuery's animate will not work with images...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use jQuery's animate with images - it just doesn't work.

Use plain css, like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/26j6P/9/

Here's the css...

```
.logo {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/300x100/ffffff/000000.png&text=first') no-repeat center top;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.logo:hover {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x100/ffffff/000000.png&text=second');
}
```

Comment: @TusharGupta I didn't down-vote you.  After checking your example though, it's not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: oh sorry i thought it was you sorry again :)

Comment: Hmm, I was overthinking again :)
Thanks @Archer.

Comment: This only works on Chrome. background-image animation is not officialy included in W3C.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot animate non numerical properties with `.animate()`

Comment: Thank you for your constructive answer.

Answer (score 4):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/26j6P/12/)

```
$('.logo').hover(

    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 'fast', function () {
            $(this)
                .css({
                    'background-image': 'url(http://placehold.it/300x100/ffffff/000000.png&text=second)'
                })
                .animate({
                    opacity: 1
                });
        });
    },

    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 'fast', function () {
            $(this)
                .css({
                    'background-image': 'url(http://placehold.it/300x100/ffffff/000000.png&text=first)'
                })
                .animate({
                    opacity: 1
                });
        });
});
```

Comment: That's not what animate does (or would do if it worked for images).  The OP is looking for one background image fading into another, not fading out first.

Comment: That's correct. Although Tushar's solution works well, I don't like fading-out / fading-in, I would prefer fading from one image to the other.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a bit late. But if there's anyone who needs to do this, there's a jquery plugin for that. Go to the following link, scroll down to demos, and choose Using Backstretch as a slideshow. It works fine.

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Comment: Not bad! Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:-

```
$('.logo').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css("background-image",
                    "url(http://placehold.it/300x100/ffffff/000000.png&text=second)"); 
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css("background-image",
                    "url(http://placehold.it/300x100/ffffff/000000.png&text=first)"); 
    }
);
```

Comment: This is working, but it's not fading... I need something less aggressive, with a fade...

Answer (score 1):

I saw someone saying you can't do it with `jQuery`, well here is my example and it works. `$(".bannerImages img")` is calling my image directly, so we can change its attribute using `$(this)`. Once that's done you can call `$(this)` and change its `attr`, and also add an animation.

```
$(".bannerImages img").animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
     $(this)
         .attr({'src': 'images/mainSlider/ps1.jpg'})
         .animate({opacity: 1});
});
```

Comment: Two problems: he wants to fade one image over the other and also he has background images, not an `<img src="..."/>` tag.