# jQuery animate does not work with background-image

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I want to change the background image of a container using the animate of jQuery. I tried this but it doesn't work and there are no compilation errors:

```
$("#main-container").animate(
{"background-image": 'url("images/background2.png")'},2000);
```

I can do it with the css but I want the animate effect.

```
$("#main-container").css(
{"background-image": 'url("images/background2.png")'});
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: How about animating the opacity of `#main-container` instead?

Comment: @Digzol its not what I want to do. I can change the opacity, it works, but I want to change the image.

Comment: Animating an URL, what would you expect as result??? Please check DOC to see how is supposed to work jQuery `animate()` method. And please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You are trying to do something that jQuery doesn't support. `animate` works on numerical values (as well as the constants `hide` and `show`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no animation for `background-image` in jQuery ( I'm not sure about the UI ) but you may can achieve this effect with css transition. Try give a transition with 2 seconds and an ease, it should apply this effect in every changes in the element ( don't forget the crossbrowser issue)

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

You can also make it happen animating a fade out, changing the image and then animate a fade in

```
$("#main-container").animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function(){
$(this).css({"background-image": 'url("images/background2.png")').animate({opacity:1},{duration:1000})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Html:**

```
<div id="main-container"></div>
```

**Css:**

```
 #main-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#main-container')
    .animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
        $(this)
            .css({'background-image': 'url(images/background2.png)'})
            .animate({opacity: 1});
    });
```

For further reference please see the below link.

[How do I change the background image using jQuery animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630947/how-do-i-change-the-background-image-using-jquery-animation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS transition:

CSS:

```
#bgDiv {
    width: 250px; 
    height: 250px;
    /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    -webkit-transition-property:background-image;
    -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-transition-delay:0s;
    /* Standard syntax */
    transition-property: background-image;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.background1 {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-250-250-5.jpg");
}

.background2 {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-250-250-7.jpg");
}
```

HTML:

```
<script>
    function backgroundChange(){
    $("#bgDiv").removeClass("background1").addClass("background2");
    };
</script>
<p onclick="backgroundChange()">Click Me</p>
<div id="bgDiv" class="background1"></div>
```

I created a sample for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/CjL7r/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use jQuery's animate with images - it just doesn't work.[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18759559/2260614)

But a way to get the solution.[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18759591/2260614)

[A working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V6zUC/2/)

```
setTimeout(animate, 2000);

function animate() {
    $('#main-container').animate({}, 'fast', function () {
        $(this).css({
            'background-image': 'url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YKUD.jpg)'
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery plugin for color manipulation and animation support :
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

jQuery `animate()` method on `backgroundColor`  will not work without this plugin.