# jQuery gradual change of the block's background

Tags: jquery

I have jquery carousel on my page with a few images. I find current image, get data-parameter and use it as background-image value for `div`

```
slideItems.removeClass('current');
slideItems.eq(currentSlide).addClass('current');
var current_image_src = $('.carousel .slideItem.current img').data('bg-image-src');
$('.conteiner').css('background-image', 'url(http:' + current_image_src + ')');
```

but with this code background image changes sharply.
 Is there any way to change background image gradually using  `animate()` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animate background image change with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983957/animate-background-image-change-with-jquery) or [How do I change the background image using jQuery animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630947/how-do-i-change-the-background-image-using-jquery-animation)

Answer (score -1):

One of the solutions would be adding `transition: background-image 1s` to your `conteiner` class, and then just change the background image.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r5oLyq7L/)