# pseudo elements work for javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello guys am working on a colorpicker named colpick,
i am using .css() for changing the colors of different elements and i uses same .css() a repeatedly in my js and the elements are more so i started var the elements and using var for them something like this

```
var colorElement = "a, upper"
$(colorElement).css('color', '#' + hex);
```

but i also wants to edit the color/style of the element when we hover, and all then when i try to add elements with :hover or :link or :focus or active,etc like this

```
var colorElement = "a:hover, upper:focus, headline:active, bar, footer"
$(colorElement).css('color', '#' + hex);
```

then it stop working (those pseudo containing elements not work)
so any idea how i can use them ?

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried forcing important to override other styles? `$(colorElement).css('color', '#' + hex + ' !important');`

Comment: You cannot modify the style of pseudo-elements that way, as they are not in the DOM. You can add/remove classes (or other attributes, for that matter) on the elements, and then create CSS rules that affect the pseudo-elements. You can also dynamically create CSS rules (that is, update `<style>` element contents).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery does not create CSS rules, it only changes the current DOM. So to change CSS style after hover, focus, etc. you must add methods that will change it.

see [how-to-define-the-css-hover-state-in-a-jquery-selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051440/how-to-define-the-css-hover-state-in-a-jquery-selector)

```
$(".myclass, .myclass2").hover(function(e) { 
    $(this).css("color",e.type === "mouseenter"?"red":"transparent") 
})
```

---

**Update:** Look at [CSSX](https://github.com/krasimir/cssx) which can change CSS styles dynamically:

```
var sheet = cssx();
var rule = sheet.add('a:hover, upper:focus, headline:active, bar, footer');
var setColor = function (hex) {
   return { 'color': '#' + hex };
};

//...

rule.update(setColor('ff0000'));
```

Comment: but that only profitable for hover, and if i do like that for others then the js can become a bit bigger in size as i have to use same bunch of elements many times and for every  hover, active,link,etc i have to create a new function. do you know any way to involve all all elements containing pseudo to be done in one go ?

Comment: @HMR you can use multiple selects `$('el1, el2, el3, ...')` and you can register handler for more events `$(...).on('event1 event2 event3 ...', function() {...})`. But this is something jQuery was not designed for so expect lots of messy methods... You may alternatively try to change CSS using custom properties (`body.style.setProperty('--color', newValue)`) or document stylesheets (`document.styleSheets[0].cssRules`) but it will not work in all browsers.

Comment: @HMR look at https://github.com/krasimir/cssx . It may be what you are looking for.