# jQuery: Changing the hover color with a color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change the hover color with a color picker.

This is what I have tried:

```js
// First Try

$("input[type=color]").change(function(e) {
  var pickedColor = e.target.value;
  // $("body").css("background-color", pickedColor);
  $("div:hover").css("color", pickedColor);
});


// Second Try

$("input[type=color]").change(function(e) {
  var pickedColor = e.target.value;
  // $("body").css("background-color", pickedColor);
  $(".hover").css("color", pickedColor);
});

$("div").hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("hover");
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial;
  cursor: default;
}

div {
  color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

div:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hello</div>

<input type="color">
```

Unfortunately, both does not work. The color picker makes it a bit complex, I guess. Could somebody help me please?

Would be very thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 2nd (using jquery `hover()`), you're adding `.hover` class to the div, which is working fine, *but* the css `div:hover` is take precedence so showing in orange

The (updated) issue with the colour being dynamic (from a colour picker) means you can't use css classes.   (You can, but it's a bit hacky where you add a `<style>` element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21051833/2181514, but not really usable if it can change multiple times).

You also can't style `:pseudo` (like `:hover`) elements directly.

Leaving the option to use `.hover()`.

```js
// Setup the colour
$("input[type=color]").change(function(e) {
  var pickedColor = e.target.value;
  $("div.hoverme").data("hovercolour", pickedColor);
});

// Set the colour on hover/unhover

$("div").hover(function() {
  var pickedColor = $(this).data("hovercolour");
  $(this).css("color", pickedColor);
}, function() {
  var normalColor = $(this).data("normalcolour")
  $(this).css("color", normalColor);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
}

div {
  color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hoverme" data-hovercolour="orange" data-normalcolour="red">Hello</div>

<input type="color">
```

Here, rather than use a global variable for the colours, I've stored the two colours in `data-` attributes along with the default `orange` - which jquery can read when it's time to hover

Comment: Hey, I'm so sorry, I had to update the question because I'm working with a color picker. And your solution doesn't work in this case. Would be very cool if you could take a look at it again! :)

Answer (score -1):

- setup git repo
- Create a webpage with a 24x24 grid of square divs
- Set up a “hover” effect so that the grid divs change color when your mouse passes over them, leaving a (pixelated) trail through your grid like a pen would. the color trail should get darker so after 10 + pass color will get darker/black .
- Add a button to the top of the screen that will send the user a popup asking for the number of squares per side for the new grid.
- add the color picker so user can select which color he wants draw
- add the button which will tricker eraser so on hover of div it will remove the color