# How to change background on every 5s

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have image `background.jpg` as the background. Every 10s, how to load a new background `background_n.jpg` which stays for 100ms and then back to `background.jpg` and so on?

Comment: Isn't that the interval where seizures can occur??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function change_background( new_image_source ) {

  var myimage = $( '#myimage' );

  myimage.attr( 'src', new_image_source );

  setTimeout( function () {

    change_background( 'new image source here' );

  }, 10000);

}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example (that does not need jQuery to work) :

```
var rotate = false;
function setbackground(){
  window.setTimeout( "setbackground()", 5000);
  newImage = rotate ? 'url(pict1.jpg)' : 'url(pict2.jpg)';
  rotate = !rotate;
  document.getElementById('change').style.backgroundImage = newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `setInterval` and `setTimeout`

```
window.setInterval(function(){    
   window.setTimeout(function(){
       $('div').css('background-image','url(background.jpg)');
   },100);
    $('div').css('background-image','url(background_n.jpg)');
},10000);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/M56A6/

Answer (score 2):

- You can use [`setTimeout(function, timeout)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) (plain Javascript function) to set a `function` (which you can define) to run after `timeout` milliseconds

  For example (the alert will be displayed after 10 seconds):

  ```
  setTimeout(function () {
       alert('I am running!');
  }, 10000);
  ```
- You can [change an element's background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253689/switching-a-div-background-image-with-jquery) with:

  ```
  $(element).css('background-image', 'url(xy.jpg)')
  ```
- Make sure you preload you background images before using them.
- I'd advise against using `setInterval()` for this (for such small intervals, it could stack up), use a chain of `setTimeout()`s to set up the repeating action.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` to run a function every n seconds, and `setTimeout` for the code that changes the background image back:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $('body').css('backgroundImage', 'url(background_n.jpg)');
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').css('backgroundImage', 'url(background.jpg)');
  }, 100);
}, 10 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// original BG: #95a5a6
// new BG: #1abc9c

var bgTimer = window.setInterval(toggleBG, 10000); // every 10 sec toggleBG

function toggleBG() {
  document.body.style.background = "#1abc9c" // Update BG 
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.style.background = "#95a5a6" // return to Original BG after 1000ms
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #95a5a6;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="header">BG change with Time</h1>
</body>
```

> Use `url('---')` instead of hex colors.

> `100ms` is negligible to notice a change so used `1000ms` for this example.

HOPE THIS GIVE YOU IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript's `setTimeout()` function
or
jQuery

```
d = new Date();
$("#myimg").attr("src", "/myimg.jpg?"+d.getTime());
```