# Change 'background-image' in 'body' tag after specific time interval

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
body{
    background-image: "image.jpg";
    }
```

How can I change the background image suppose 'image1.jpg,image2.jpg...'
after 5s.

Found this script on StackOverflow for changing the image, but I also need to change it after few seconds and also **Without Click**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("image2.jpg")');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change background on every 5s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440952/how-to-change-background-on-every-5s) You would need to change `10000` to `5000` though.

Comment: @yuriy636, I did check toggle the background-image, without clicking i.e. by time interval and was not able to find it. Hence had to post the question. If there is any such question and I skipped it, my apologies. And Daniel solved the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. put your urls or img path inside the array, it will loop through every image. started with first one.
2. use `setInterval` if you need this keep running forever. (setTimeout will run once per call)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var urls = ['https://pp.userapi.com/c629327/v629327473/db66/r051joYFRX0.jpg', 'https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg', 'https://img.wikinut.com/img/gycf69_-6rv_5fol/jpeg/0/Best-Friends-Img-Src:Image:-FreeDigitalPhotos.net.jpeg', 'http://www.travelettes.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/IMG_3829-Medium-600x400.jpg'];

  var cout = 1;
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url("' + urls[0] + '")');
  setInterval(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("' + urls[cout] + '")');
    cout == urls.length-1 ? cout = 0 : cout++;
  }, 5000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes @DanielH, your answer is just perfect.

Comment: Everything works fine but at the end there is a blank image for 5 sec. Can you help with that? I am trying to figure out the solution,  but it's now working out.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh you are right, I found the problem. it is this line: `cout == urls.length-1 ? cout = 0 : cout++;` the array with 4 urls have length of 4 but the index are 0,1,2,3. so we need to put length-1 to match the last urls index which is 3

Comment: that's just perfect!

Answer (score 6):

you can also use a CSS animation:

```css
body {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/people/1);
  animation: chbg 15s infinite alternate;
  background-size:cover
}
@keyframes chbg {
  0% {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/1);
  background-size:cover
  }
  20% {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/7);
  background-size:cover
  }
  40% {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/6);
  background-size:cover
  }
  60% {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/2);
  background-size:cover
  }
  80% {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9);
  background-size:cover
  }
  100% {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/8);
  background-size:cover
  }
}
```

Comment: @DhavalJardosh i updated snippet with infinite animation (and decreased quality of bg , lorempixel is sometimes slow)

Comment: That's Great! I am working on smooth transition of images.
This method is quite simple.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh if you planned to fade bg, you might want to take a look at this codepen  https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/DJdja It uses animation and pseudo elements to do the fading . It is a 4 years old demo but still up to date at this time for the CSS fading effect in bg . You can rework animation for pseudos in order to include extra image and also add image to body also . Timing will need to be tuned so image are changed will element is not visible. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rmOVJM

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this . You can fill the array of colours with image paths!

```js
var counter=0;
var colours=["red","green","blue"];

$(function() {
    change();

    function change() {
       setTimeout(change,5000);
       
    $('body').css('background-color', colours[counter] );
    
    counter++;
    
    if(counter==3){ counter=0;}
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy Way To Do Is That with Function run code to chek

```js
function run(interval, frames) {
    var int = 1;
    
    function func() {
        document.body.id = "b"+int;
        int++;
        if(int === frames) { int = 1; }
    }
    
    var swap = window.setInterval(func, interval);
}

run(1000, 10); //milliseconds, frames
```

```css
#b1 { background: hsl(0, 50%, 50%); }
#b2 { background: hsl(30, 50%, 50%); }
#b3 { background: hsl(60, 50%, 50%); }
#b4 { background: hsl(90, 50%, 50%); }
#b5 { background: hsl(120, 50%, 50%); }
#b6 { background: hsl(150, 50%, 50%); }
#b7 { background: hsl(180, 50%, 50%); }
#b8 { background: hsl(210, 50%, 50%); }
#b9 { background: hsl(240, 50%, 50%); }
#b10 { background: hsl(270, 50%, 50%); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<html>

<body>

<body>



</html>
```