# How to change Background Image of input button using Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to change my button background image using javascript so i wrote a code like this but seems to be it's not working well.

```
$('#search-button-input').css('background-image', $.format("url('Images/%(color)s.png')", { color: e }));
```

e is image comes with fire the some other function.

my input tag like this

```
<input id="search-button-input" type="button" name="q" class="search-button-input"  value="search" />
```

Comment: What does `$.format` do? Edit: obviously it is supposed to subsitute the value into the string, but what does the call *actually* do?

Comment: it's uses for string concatenation like in c# does string.format('{0}/{2}',one,two); :)

Comment: @lonesomeday For reference: this is the [jQuery Format](http://jquery.bassistance.de/api-browser/plugins.html#jQueryformatStringArrayString) plugin. @Gayan Can't you use the `+` operator for concatenation?

Comment: Yes, evidently. This is likely the bit that isn't working though. If you put `console.log($.format("url('Images/%(color)s.png')", { color: e }))` immediately above the line you have there, what is logged?

Comment: Here you have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253689/switching-a-div-background-image-with-jquery Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: it's giving me a output which i expected.

Comment: @Gayan OK, can you define "not working well" please? Could you provide a live example of your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switching a DIV background image with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253689/switching-a-div-background-image-with-jquery)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, one way to do it is if you're using this function to respond to a mouseover event, an easier way to do it is with CSS itself. In CSS you can specify the style of something which is being hovered over like this:

```
element:hover { ... }
```

If this isn't what you want, then you can do something like this for example:

```
element.setAttribute("style", "color: blue; background-color: red");
```

Comment: no luck it's not working for me and i'm suppose to use this for mover hover image change. thanks for reply