# how do i change css background image using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#picture').css('height', '666px');
    $('#picture').click(function () {
        $(this).css('background-image', "url('../images/picture_2.jpg')");
    });
});
```

in the above code, the `height` is successfully changed to 666px but the background image does not change at all (remains the original one).

When I change the `background-image` to 'none' instead of "url('../images/picture_2.jpg')" it does make the background image disappear though.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try removing single quotes from inside of the url()

Comment: Which browser?  It might just not be loading it..

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand chrome and internet explorer 8

Comment: possible duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253689/switching-a-div-background-image-with-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that the URL you're putting in is incorrect. The URL should be relative to the *page you're on*. I bet your URL is relative to your CSS style sheet. In general, just use absolute paths when doing this in JS.

You also don't need the single quotes surrounding the path.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided should work fine. I think the image location you mentioned `../images/picture_2.jpg` is incorrect. Check if you could see the image from that location in firebug.

I tried the same code and it worked fine for me. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/w6gQf/) here

Answer (score 1):

Correct the path to the image.

Path to the image will be calculated from the root of the site, not from the css.

Just to clarify :

Height will change on the load of the page, Where as Background image will change only if #picture element will be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8w52U/1/), which works for me.

How does this differ from what you've tried?