# HTML/CSS: Background Image from raw image data, not url

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

i get the raw image data of a png-image from a webserver, and want to use it as the background image of a div-element. is this possible without saving the data as an image-file first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
document.getElementById('e').src = 'data:image/png;base64,ton_of_crap';
```

In that Wikipedia article, there is code for PHP and Python that outputs base-64 encoded images. You can just shove that into the `url()` of a CSS file (or the `src` attribute of a `<img />` tag) and it should work.

Comment: the image is not base64 encoded, so i tried to leave the ";base64" out, but nevertheless the image doesnt show...

Comment: It needs to be base64-encoded. By "raw-data" what do you mean? Like the contents of the image file, or a special URL that shows you a generated image?

Comment: its the contents of the image file starting with
?PNG

IHDR (...)

Comment: How exactly do you get the raw data?

Comment: i get it as response from a REST-Server using ajax

Comment: i'm trying to enode it myself using this encoder now: http://ntt.cc/2008/01/19/base64-encoder-decoder-with-javascript.html  
to set the image i use this code:  
$(".newsflashImage").css("background-image","url('data:image/png;base64," + encode64(data) + "')");  
but it still doesnt work...

Comment: i think the problem now is the base64 encoder as a bas64 encoded image i got from the web works. i also tried this encoder http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html but it still doesnt work.

Comment: i solved the problem by base64 encoding the image on the server, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried (with jQuery):

```
$('#divID').css("background-image", "url(/myimage.png)");
```

From [Switching a DIV background image with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253689/switching-a-div-background-image-with-jquery)

Comment: put the URL of the server in the css if that server is accessible by the client of course