# How to change background-image of a div?

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

CSS

```
background-image:url(../back/back01.jpg); //this works
```

JS

```
function switchRight(){
    $('#slider00').css("background-image","url(../back/back02.jpg)");
}
```

back01.jpg is removed, but back02.jpg is not loaded.

Comment: Check this once. It may helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253689/switching-a-div-background-image-with-jquery

Comment: Please check your image path, might be wrong relative path causing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your css files in folder

```
function switchRight(){
    $('#slider00').css("background-image","url(back/back02.jpg)");
}
```

Please check

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you image is exist in defined folder.

You can also give css class by below code.

```
  .imageclass
  {
    background-image:url(../back/back01.jpg);
  }

   function switchRight(){
     $('#slider00').addClass('imageclass'); // same way you can use remove class
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the path to the background image. When setting it via css the path is relative to where your css file is located. When you do it in javascript use path relative to the root of the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyOne. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check the the path for image. The first is based on the css file's current path, while the second is based on web site root.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#slider00').css("background-image", "url(../back/back02.jpg)");

$('#slider00').click(function()
{
  // do my image switching logic here.
});
```