# Set background image in CSS using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set the background image for one of my html element using jquery

```
<div class="rmz-srchbg">
    <input type="text" id="globalsearchstr" name="search" value="" class="rmz-txtbox">
    <input type="submit" value="&nbsp;" id="srchbtn" class="rmz-srchico">
    <br style="clear:both;">
</div>

$("#globalsearchstr").focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().css("background", "url(/images/r-srchbg_white.png) no-repeat;");
});
```

but this never works.On focus only change happens is that a style attribute is added to HTML, like this

```
<div class="rmz-srchbg" style="">

</div>
```

No change in CSS happens.

Comment: what about using absolute path? Check in console if your relative path is accurate

Comment: **CSS** $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ') no-repeat');

Comment: this wont work background-image is wrong it should be backgroundImage

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="rmz-srchbg">
    <input type="text" id="globalsearchstr" name="search" value="" class="rmz-txtbox">
    <input type="submit" value="&nbsp;" id="srchbtn" class="rmz-srchico">
    <br style="clear:both;">
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
   $('#globalsearchstr').on('focus mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).parent().css("background", "url(/images/r-srchbg_white.png) no-repeat");
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

Use :

```
 $(this).parent().css("background-image", "url(/images/r-srchbg_white.png) no-repeat;");
```

instead of

```
 $(this).parent().css("background", "url(/images/r-srchbg_white.png) no-repeat;");
```

More examples you cand see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253689/switching-a-div-background-image-with-jquery)

Comment: to use `background-image` in jquery, you should use `backgroundImage` !

Comment: both methods are accepted.

Comment: For sure you can. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
 $(this).parent().css("backgroundImage", "url('../images/r-srchbg_white.png') no-repeat");
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. +1 for `''` in `url()`. This works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("#globalsearchstr").focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().css("background", "url('../images/r-srchbg_white.png') no-repeat");
});
```

Comment: Not working.Still same problem(explained in question)

Comment: @Athul try now, what is error?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi-colon after `no-repeat`, in the url and try it .

```
$("#globalsearchstr").focus(function(){
    $(this).parent().css("background", "url(/images/r-srchbg_white.png) no-repeat");
});
```

Comment: "background" property is not correct. "background-image" you wanna say.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the semicolon in the css rule string:

```
$(this).parent().css("background", "url(/images/r-srchbg_white.png) no-repeat");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="rmz-srchbg">
  <input type="text" id="globalsearchstr" name="search" value="" class="rmz-txtbox">
  <input type="submit" value="&nbsp;" id="srchbtn" class="rmz-srchico">
  <br style="clear:both;">
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#globalsearchstr').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).parent().css("background", "black");
  });
});
```