# How do I use javascript to change HTML of page

Tags: javascript, html

How do I use JavaScript to change the HTML of a webpage? 
Temporarily, only for the time they are on the webpage
I am making a chrome extension to change the 404 that I get at
randomsiteisay.com/randomsitepage 
Pretty much that the unused webpage gets its HTML changed to what I want it to be.

What I have:

```js
var body1 = '\
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\
<div id="content">\
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>\
  <h2>Dont go here</h2>\
  <h3>Thats RT, EWW</h3>\
 </fieldset></div>\
</div>\
'

var aNewBodyElement = document.createElement("body");

aNewBodyElement.id = "newBodyElement";
document.body = aNewBodyElement;
document.getElementById("newBodyElement").innerHTML = body1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the last 4 lines by:

```
document.querySelector("body").innerHTML= body1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = body1;
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate HTML using javascript just use:

```
document.getElementById("body"); 
//and then change the background of the body
```

Or if you want to try jQuery you could do:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(...)')
```

might help: [Switching a DIV background image with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253689/switching-a-div-background-image-with-jquery)