# Toggle Background Image HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple question, I need to make a switch/button in which the user clicks it to toggle the background image to on or off

Here's the code:

```
body style = "background-image: url('WebsiteBG.jpg')"
```

And here's the CSS for it:

```
<style>
  body{
    background-size: cover; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    background-attachment: fixed 
  }
</style>
```

Comment: have you attempted any js or jquery?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switching a DIV background image with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253689/switching-a-div-background-image-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can do this using `jQuery` or `javaScript`. The basic idea would be to toggle the class of the `body` tag. See an example below :

**JavaScript Solution :**

*HTML:*

```
<body>
    <div style="color:red;">Some random text here</div>
    <input type="button" id="btnBack" value="Toggle Background" />
</body>
```

*CSS:*

```
body {
    background-size: cover; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    background-attachment: fixed 
  }

.BgClass {
    background-image: url('http://freedomwallpaper.com/wallpaper2/funky-wallpaper-hd.jpg');
}
```

*javaScript*

```
var btnBack = document.getElementById('btnBack');
btnBack.addEventListener('click',function() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('BgClass');
});
```

You can see this here -> http://jsfiddle.net/qagdvft6/

**jQuery Solution**

```js
$('#btnBack').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('BgClass');
});
```

```css
body{
    background-size: cover; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    background-attachment: fixed 
  }

.BgClass {
    background-image: url('http://freedomwallpaper.com/wallpaper2/funky-wallpaper-hd.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div style="color:red;">Some random text here</div>
    <input type="button" id="btnBack" value="Toggle Background">
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it was simple to do with jQuery but I somewhat forgot about jQuery codes. Nonetheless thanks a lot!

Comment: @SamiNofal Glad to help Sami! :)

Comment: @SamiNofal If this answer helped you, then please mark it as the answer so that it will help others in the future who stumble upon this question!!!

Comment: Non-jQuery solution: `document.body.classList.toggle('BgClass');`. [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en_US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is supported in IE10+.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks!! I have added the JavaScript solution to the answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple thing to achieve using jQuery.

You can see my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qwnLj4tj/

With jQuery I am toggling a style class on the body when the button is clicked:

```
$('.my-button').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('active-class');
    return false;
});
```

And with css I am just applying the styles for the toggleClass:

```
body.active-class {
    background: url('URL/TO/BGIMAGE.EXT');
}
```