# using jQuery to change a background image

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to use jQuery to change the background image in a table cell, the table cell has its own class of ".active". I am using jQuery to change other elements in the same place and they all work fine so i think i must have something wrong in the syntax. the function i am using executes after a button is clicked.
*my code:*

```
function vehicle(arg){
  $(".active").css("color", "blue");  
  $(".active").css("background-image", "url(../img/car.png)");
};
```

css:

```
.active{
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-right: 1px solid none;
```

the first line executes fine, i have tried the following code plus changed the picture size in every way i can think of :

```
   $(".active").css("background-image", "../img/car.png");
   $(".active").css("background-image", "url('../img/car.png')");
```

can anyone point out what i did wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching a DIV background image with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253689/switching-a-div-background-image-with-jquery)

Comment: @miguelmpn How can that be a dupe? Not dupe.

Answer (score 9):

You need to put the `.css()` relative to the page. So try:

```
$(".active").css("background-image", "url('img/car.png')");
```

Assuming the `img/` is in the same directory as the page, this should work. Else use the relative paths to the root.

Comment: its odd, if i use the ',' in between "background-image"and  "url('img/car.png')"  the code at the begining of my script wont run, but if i use a : my other code works but the background wont work

Comment: @LucyViolet Using `:` is for objects. I have used a function here.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try the below syntax to set the background image dynamically

```
$(".active").attr("style", "background-image: url('your url')");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set a CSS class to change the image.

**CSS:**

```
.img1{
    background-image:img/car1.png;
}

.img2{
    background-image:img/car2.png;
}
```

**jQUERY:**

```
$(".active").removeClass('img1').addClass('img2');
```

Comment: That's not the question. first u can't add a background-image like that, and create a class per image is not a good way. he just want to have the good url.