# Switching between css stylesheets

Tags: jquery, css

So, unlike other questions about this, I want to use this code from here: [How do I switch my CSS stylesheet using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846980/how-do-i-switch-my-css-stylesheet-using-jquery)

I need to switch between multiple css styles instead of two with the following code (jQuery):

```
$('#backgroundDefault').click(function (){ $('link[href="style1.css"]').attr('href','style.css'); }); $('#background1').click(function (){ $('link[href="style.css"]').attr('href','style1.css'); });
```

Can this work? I like the smooth transition between styles, unlike many other code samples I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work. Whether `<link>` is either in the `<head>` or `<body>`.

Here's a basic sample,

```js
var isToggled = false;
$(function() {
  $('#btnSwitchCss').on('click', function() {
    isToggled = !isToggled;

    if (isToggled) {
      $("link[href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css']").attr('href', '../');
    } else {
      $("link[href='../']").attr('href', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    }
  })

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center"> Switch CSS Style </h2>
  <button id="btnSwitchCss">Switch</button>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Haven't used Javascript as much as Jquery, could I switch between 4 styles?

Comment: @Akidus Yes, you can switch to multiple styles with no problem. But this is such a bad practice though I can't fully prove it. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: What do you recommend? Unless, you have an idea for switching between wallpaper on the same web page.

Comment: @Akidus Yeah, assign each background wallpaper as their own class in your css. And switch the class instead.

Comment: You you have an example? For some reason, I can't think of the code right now.

Comment: @Akidus Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4917267/1627271). And there should be lot of samples out there..